# How to choose PyTorch Conv1d input parameters?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, conv1d

I am new to machine learning and I want to know how to specify Conv1d parameters for time series analysis. My input is a vector of 3 features - x, y, z acceleration respectively, and my target is only 0 or 1 (binary classification). My dataset contains 1200 1-dimension vectors with length of 3. Here's the code I've written:

```
class my_CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(5, 3, 1200),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(1, 3),
            nn.Conv1d(5, 3, 400),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(1, 2),
            nn.Flatten()
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)
```

I've written `nn.Conv1d(5, 3, 1200)` because I've read that 1st parameter stands for number of batches (I have 5), then number of channels (I guess here I have 3) and input shape (here I have 1200 if I understood it correctly).

However, when I try to start learning, I receive an error:
`RuntimeError: Expected 2D (unbatched) or 3D (batched) input to conv1d, but got input of size: [3]`

The code for learning is like this:

```
    for epoch in range(10):
        for X, y in zip(dataset, labels):
            X = [float(x) for x in X]
            X = tensor(np.array(X), dtype=torch.float32)
            y = tensor(np.array(y), dtype=torch.float32)
            X, y = X.to('cpu'), y.to('cpu')
            ypred = clf_acc(X)
            loss = loss_fn(ypred, y)

            opt.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            opt.step()
        print(f"Epoch:{epoch}, loss is {loss_fn.item()}")
```

I will highly appreciate your help and comments. I know there are same questions, but after reading the answers I receive even more questions since each case is individual.

Comment: No, the 1st param is the number of input channels, the 2nd is the number of output channels, and the 3rd is kernel size. Also, Conv1d expects either 2D or 3D (batched) inputs. You can find more details on: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv1d.html.